# Compare two files with awk or sed

Tags: shell, text, sed, awk

This must be easy for you

Here is file1 (one column)

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

and here is file2 (two columns)

```
2 yay
3 ups
4 wow
8 hey
```

There must be a simple one liner to print out lines in file1 that don´t match to file2

Comment: Note that the `join` and `comm` solutions require the input files to be sorted, which they happen to be in this question. The `awk` solution does not care if not sorted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next;}!($0 in a)' file2 file1
```

or using join with -v, as @Michael suggested:

```
join -v1 file1 file2
```

both  will print :

```
1
5
6
7
9
```

Comment: Can you please explain your awk one-liner for +1? :)

Comment: @Jaypal the awk save file2 in an array, index is field1; then for each line in file1 check if it is an index of the array, to do the comparation. the ++ is nothing special but set a value to the element. a[$1]=1; works too. but ++ is faster for typing. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by combining `cut` and `comm`:

```
cut -d' ' -f1 file2 | comm -13 - file1
```

You might also consider `join`, depending on how you want to handle repeated lines.

Answer (score 2):

This sed solution might work for you:

```
{ seq 1 10; echo -e "2 yay\n3 ups\n4 wow\n8 hey"; } | sort -n | 
sed '1{h;d};H;${x;s/\(\S\+\)\n\1[^\n]*\n//g;p};d'
1
5
6
7
9
10
```

Explanation: Sort the files numerically then using `sed` slurp the file in to the hold space (HS). At end of file swap to the HS and then delete lines with the duplicate keys.