# comparing 2 files and extracting elements from file

Tags: shell, awk

I have two files. one has list of names (only one column) and the second file is with three columns with names, phone number, country.

What I want is to extract the data of the people whose names are not present in file 1, but only present in file2.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `cat file1 `
   do
      cat file2 | awk '{ if ($1 != "'$i'") {print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 }}'>>NonResp
   done
```

What I get is a weird result with more data than expected.

Kindly help.

Comment: What has this to do with PYthon?

Comment: After a two-minute search, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181974/compare-two-files-with-awk-or-sed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `grep`:

```
grep -v -F -f file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print $1}' file2 | comm -1 -3 file1 - | join file2 -
```

The files must already be sorted for this to work properly.
Explanation:

```
=> awk '{print $1}' file2 |
```

print only the first fileld of file2 and feed it to the next command (|)

```
=> comm -1 -3 file1 - |
```

compare file1 and the output of the last command (-) and suppress lines only in file1 (-1) as well as lines in both files (-3); that leaves lines in file2 only and feed this to the next command (|)

```
=> join file2 -
```

join the original file2 and the output from the last command (-) and write out the fields fo the matching lines (whitespace between fields is truncated, however)

Testcase:

```
cat <<EOF >file1
alan
bert
cindy
dave
fred
sunny
ted
EOF

cat <<EOF >file2
bert    01      AU
cindy   03      CZ
ginny   05      CN
ted     07      CH
zorro   09      AG
EOF

awk '{print $1}' file2 | comm -1 -3 file1 - | join file2 -
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming the field delimiter as "`,`" in file2

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}!($1 in a)' file1 file2
```

if "`,`" is not the delimiter ,then simply

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}!($1 in a)' file1 file2
```

would be sufficient.