# Find the difference between two files

Tags: awk

I have the following situation:

The file1.dat is like:

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 1
```

and the file2.dat is like:

```
1 2
2 1
2 3
3 4
```

I want to find the differences between the second file from the first. I tried wit `grep -v -f file1 file2` but my real files are bigger than this two and when I tried with it the shell never ended is work.

The result should be:

```
2 3
3 4
```

The files are sorted and they have the same number of elements. Any way to find a solution with awk?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181974/compare-two-files-with-awk-or-sed

Comment: all lines that in file2.dat do not exist in file1.dat

Comment: why `1 3` not in result? it is in file1, but not in file2. it is difference right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems like you want lines in `file2` that are not in `file1`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' file1 file2
2 3
3 4
```

However it's simpler to use `comm`:

```
$ comm -13 file1 file2
2 3
3 4
```

Comment: why the -13 ? what does it means?

Comment: Read `man comm` `-1` to suppress the lines unique to file one and `-3` to suppress the lines common to both.. leaving only lines unique in file2.

Comment: comm is a great suggestion.  I used it to compare shellcode after awking distinct values

Comment: @ChrisSeymour . What do I change if I want records which are missing in either of files not just file2 , Dont want to use diff but awk to get missing records along with file name .